# Does PageSpeed Insights performance score somehow affect your website SEO? How much?

Tags: seo, googlebot, google-ranking

I often see that popular websites have red-orange performance scores in PageSpeed Insights. So I'm wondering if that somehow affect SEO or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, site speed has been an SEO signal used by Google since at least 2010.
https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking

However, it is a less important signal than page relevance. It's more important for mobile searches, but even so it affects about 1% of searches.

Comment: So , the affect is really low?

Answer (score 1):

Google seems to use PageSpeed Insights scores so that *very* slow sites don't appear in the search results very much.  In other words, having a horrible score can really hurt your site, but it isn't necessary to get 100/100.  If you site score at least an 80/100 I wouldn't expect improving your score to help your rankings further.

[In August 2021, Google announced](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2021/04/more-details-page-experience) that [core web vitals](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2021/04/more-details-page-experience) was a new page performance ranking factor.  At this point, I'd pay more attention to the core web vitals metrics for my site than I would to the PageSpeed Insights score.  Again, the goal isn't to be perfect.  Having acceptable scores is likely to be fine for SEO.